# Use next parameter for login_required views

Tags: django, python-3.x, url-parameters, login-required

My method to redirect a url after login, work well but the code of the template is not very sexy, can I have yours please ?
my function in views.py

```
def connexion(request):
    error = False
    n=request.GET.get('n')
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ConnexionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                if request.GET.get('n'):
                    return redirect(request.GET['n'])
                else:
                    return redirect(accueil)

            else:
                error = True
    else:
        form = ConnexionForm()

    return render(request, 'blog/connect_user.html', locals())
```

my template:

```html
<h1>Se connecter</h1>

{% if error %}
<p><strong>Utilisateur inconnu ou mauvais mot de passe.</strong></p>
{% endif %}

{%if n %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'connexion' %}?n={{ n }}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Se connecter" />
</form>
{% else %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'connexion' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Se connecter" />
</form>
{% endif %}
```

my decorator:

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name='n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
<input type="hidden" name="n" value="{{ n }}">
```

And in the view:

```
n = request.REQUEST.get('n', '')
```

Using `request.REQUEST` you can get `n` from either using POST or GET so you can still link to a URL like `/login?n=/foo/bar`. You can also do [POST/REDIRECT/GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) without problems.